# Reconstructing PostGIS geometry from ST_DumpPoints()?

Tags: postgis, postgis-3.0

The PostGIS [ST_DumpPoints](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) function seems to have enough data in the return value about the structure of geometries (in the path field):

> It returns a set of geometry_dump rows, each containing a geometry
> (geom field) and an array of integers (path field).
>
> - the geom field POINTs represent the coordinates of the supplied geometry.
> - the path field (an integer[]) is an index enumerating the coordinate positions in the elements of the supplied geometry. The indices are
>   1-based. For example, for a LINESTRING the paths are {i} where i is
>   the nth coordinate in the LINESTRING. For a POLYGON the paths are
>   {i,j} where i is the ring number (1 is outer; inner rings follow) and
>   j is the coordinate position in the ring.

*Is there a function in PostGIS to reconstruct a specific type of geometry (e.g. `MULTIPOLYGON`, or `LINESTRING`) from its point dump table to get back the original geometry?*

(I know [ST_MakeLine](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html), but I was wondering if there is a more general inverse of ST_Dump type functions.)

Answer (score 0):

No.

You will have to manually aggregate the dumped *Point* geometries according to their index and unique (row) identifier, and in a dimensional bottom-up fashion - and you will need `n-1` aggregation steps for `n` elements in the returned `path` array, to reconstruct the original geometry.